# Possibility of tracking who opened their Woocommerce Order Completed email

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce, orders

I am looking for a tool to track which users didn't receive or didn't open their Woocommerce order complete email (maybe because they didn't check their Spam filter).

I found the Follow-Ups Woocommerce extension, but this only lets you track additional emails and doesn't show you a list of all people that didn't open their mail.

Is there any other way to track Woocommerce Emails as described?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can. To track email in wordpress is complex process. You need t add Pixel Tracking Code in Email. For easiness you should any prebuilt plugin . Use check Email Tracker wordpress plugin on Email Tracker . This wordpress plugin tracks email is opened or not at receiver end. This is free plugin. I have tested it many times and it is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to integrate third party mail campaign / tracking services like [Mailchimp](http://mailchimp.com/)

Review this articles :

- https://connect.mailchimp.com/integrations/woochimp-mailchimp-for-woocommerce
- https://connect.mailchimp.com/integrations/woocommerce-mailchimp

Also review this plug-in which will allow to ingrate Mailchimp in Woocommerce.

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-mailchimp/

Comment: Thanks for the Tip with Mailchimp, but with Mailchimp I did not find any solution to track which user exactly did not open their Woocommerce "Order Completed" Email.